# how to convert sys.argv strings into list

Tags: python-3.x

I am parsing long urls through `sys.argv`

format parsing is :   "url1 ", "url2", "url3"

and output values trying to convert into list but get results like

url1, url2, url3

parsing urls :

```
 "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A6T9C2PUZSUPW&tab=&vasStoreID=","https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1916U364TPZBZ&tab=&vasStoreID="
```

output is, not valid list

```
['https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A6T9C2PUZSUPW&tab=&vasStoreID=,https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1916U364TPZBZ&tab=&vasStoreID=']
```

```
import sys

test = sys.argv[1]

print([test])
```

parsing command

```
 python test.py  "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A6T9C2PUZSUPW&tab=&vasStoreID=","https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1916U364TPZBZ&tab=&vasStoreID="
```

Comment: can you give a little more code than just the blank strings? How one should find the mistake from that, please? (the error is for sure in the code around what you have given ...) Maybe minimal working version of the script you are using. And also how you call it from command line ...

Comment: You need to make sure you are passing the urls with spaces separating them and then call `argv[1:]` to take all of them. You ar ejust taking the first one

Comment: updated plz check

Comment: As I said, replace the `,` with a simple space and then change the call to `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: You need to split your argument on the comma, but also take into account commas inside quotes. You'd be better off passing your arguments with whitespace between them than a comma.

Comment: Yes, Tomerikoo is right. Your problem is the way how you call from Terminal. The separator in shell is empty space and not comma.

Comment: @00, ...*syntactic* whitespace specifically; *literal* whitespace (whitespace-as-data) would do no good if best practices (correct quoting &c) in shell are followed.

Comment: If all your urls start with `http://` or `https://`, you could split from either of those using regex (if just `http://` for example, you could do `test.split(",http://")`). However, you really shouldn't be using `,` as separator for urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

test = sys.argv[1:]  # you want all arguments so slice to the end, 
# test is then already a list

print(test) # so no need to pack `test` into a list here, because it IS a list
```

Then call it like this:

```
python test.py  "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A6T9C2PUZSUPW&tab=&vasStoreID=" "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00ZGCKLE2&isAmazonFulfilled=0&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1916U364TPZBZ&tab=&vasStoreID="
```